# Java swing popup menu and jlist

Tags: java, swing, menu, popup, jlist

here is my problem:
I have a jList and a popup menu. When I right click the jList, the popup menu shows. The problem is that the jList item which the mouse is pointing at won't select.
And I want it to do that. When I point my cursor at an item in the list and press the right button, I want two things to happen. Select the item on which I clicked and show the popup menu.

I tried this:

```
jLists.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

     @Override
     public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            jList.setSelectedIndex(jList.locationToIndex(e.getPoint()));
     }
});

jList.setComponentPopupMenu(jPopupMenu);
```

But it only shows the popup menu.
If I delete this line:

```
jList.setComponentPopupMenu(jPopupMenu);
```

then the right-click select works (but the popup menu doesn't show).

So, what do you think is the best way to make these two functions (both) work ?

Thanks and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Don't do `setComponentPopupMenu`. In the `MouseAdapter` do the following:

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)  {check(e);}
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {check(e);}

public void check(MouseEvent e) {
    if (e.isPopupTrigger()) { //if the event shows the menu
        jList.setSelectedIndex(jList.locationToIndex(e.getPoint())); //select the item
        jPopupMenu.show(jList, e.getX(), e.getY()); //and show the menu
    }
}
```

This should work.

**EDIT:** The code now checks both `press` and `release` events, because some platforms show popups when mouse presses and some other on release. See [the Swing tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html#popup) for more info.

Comment: Not a big fan of untested code, but was compelled to give an up vote for checking `isPopupTrigger()` - good call.

Comment: To be honest I would go with `if(e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3)` instead of `if(e.isPopupTrigger())` for a very simple reason the trigger method returns false for me always. Otherwise I would code it 100% the same @jmendeth +1.

Comment: @Boro:  Interesting point ( & yet another affirmation for 'tested code' ;).  What OS/Java are you running?

Comment: I've updated the code to check both `press` and `release` events.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson Win7 Java 6u25 even after re-coding in a similar fashion (one method for all mouse event types) I always have false from `e.isPopupTrigger()` method. Can anyone confirm if on Linux and/or Mac `if(e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3)` would work?

Comment: Ok now it is fine I forgot to remove the `
  table.setComponentPopupMenu(popup);` thus on release I didn't get the trigger. So on Wins you need the release too. Good to know :)

Comment: Note that avoiding `setComponentPopupMenu` in this way means that you won't be able to invoke the popup menu via the keyboard.

Comment: @RangiKeen good point. Maybe it could be done more cleanly with an overriden `JPopupMenu`.

Comment: @RangiKeen Oh god, I just realized this is what your answer is about! Upvoted.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to continue to use `setComponentPopupMenu` (which is nice because it handles mouse and keyboard invocations of the popup in a cross platform way), you could override `JPopupMenu.show(Component, int, int)` to select the appropriate row.

```
JPopupMenu jPopupMenu = new JPopupMenu() {
    @Override
    public void show(Component invoker, int x, int y) {
        int row = jList.locationToIndex(new Point(x, y));
        if (row != -1) {
            jList.setSelectedIndex(row);
        }
        super.show(invoker, x, y);
    }
};

jList.setComponentPopupMenu(jPopupMenu);
```

Note that when your popup is invoked via the keyboard (and you don't also override `getPopupLocation` on your target component), the x, y location you get in `JPopupMenu.show` will be the midpoint of your component. If there's already a selection in this case you probably don't want to change the selection.

The solution I came up with to solve the keyboard vs. mouse invocation problem was to set a client property on the component in an override of `getPopupLocation` and then check it when showing the popup. The argument to `getPopupLocation` will be `null` when invoked via the keyboard. Here's the core code (perhaps implemented in a utility class available to your component and its popup menu).

```
private static final String POPUP_TRIGGERED_BY_MOUSE_EVENT = "popupTriggeredByMouseEvent"; // NOI18N

public static Point getPopupLocation(JComponent invoker, MouseEvent event)
{
    boolean popupTriggeredByMouseEvent = event != null;
    invoker.putClientProperty(POPUP_TRIGGERED_BY_MOUSE_EVENT, Boolean.valueOf(popupTriggeredByMouseEvent));
    if (popupTriggeredByMouseEvent)
    {
        return event.getPoint();
    }
    return invoker.getMousePosition();
}

public static boolean isPopupTriggeredByMouseEvent(JComponent invoker)
{
    return Boolean.TRUE.equals(invoker.getClientProperty(POPUP_TRIGGERED_BY_MOUSE_EVENT));
}
```

Then override `getPopupLocation` in your component:

```
@Override
public Point getPopupLocation(MouseEvent event)
{
    return PopupMenuUtils.getPopupLocation(this, event);
}
```

and call `isPopupTriggeredByMouseEvent` in an override of `JPopupMenu.show` to determine whether or not to select the row at the popup location (or whatever action may make sense for the underlying component):

```
JPopupMenu jPopupMenu = new JPopupMenu() {
    @Override
    public void show(Component invoker, int x, int y) {
        int row = jList.locationToIndex(new Point(x, y));
        if (row != -1 && PopupMenuUtils.isPopupTriggeredByMouseEvent((JComponent) invoker)) {
            jList.setSelectedIndex(row);
        }
        super.show(invoker, x, y);
    }
};
```

Comment: the missing part is `jList=new JList<ContactItem>() {
            @Override
            public Point getPopupLocation(MouseEvent event) {
                return JListUtility.getPopupLocation(this, event);
            }
        };`

Comment: Thanks, @palindrom. I updated my answer to include the `getPopupLocation` usage